# Local Storage not working?

Tags: javascript, html, url, web, local-storage

I have a test with several webpages where by clicking through them, it saves your last URL,
their is a second button that, when clicked, it takes you too the variable that URL variable stored on local storage.

```
<head></head>
<script type="text/jscript">
function pagestore() {
localStorage.setItem('page','uronpg1.html');
}
function pagego() {
var spage = localStorage.getItem('page');
window.location = spage;
}

</script>
<body> <div id="forward" onclick="pagestore()"><a href="uronpg2.html">GO TOP PAGE2></a></div>
<div id="goto" onlick="pagego()">GOTO SAVED</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This page links to the uronpg2.html

```
<script type="text/jscript">
function pagestore() {
localStorage.setItem('page','uronpg2.html');
}
function pagego() {
var spage = localStorage.getItem('page');
window.location = spage;
}


</script>
<body> <div id="forward" onclick="pagestore()"><a href="uronpg3.html">GO TOP PAGE3></a></div>
<div id="goto" onlick="pagego()">GOTO SAVED</div>
</body>
```

Which keeps linking until its on uronpg5.html then comes back to uronpg1.html.
But for some reason the PAGEGO CLICK DOES NOT WORK, im not even fully sure why. I think it has to do with local storage.
If you have any advice i'd be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `div` with an id of `goto`.

The attribute `onlick` should be `onclick`.

Comment: that's a pretty humorous typo. Good eye @pln

Comment: Hmmm.. even stackoverflow isn't doing correct syntax highlighting